# Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' - Spring boot doesn´t accept my entityManager

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

it is the first time I write in here since i am learning programming. I am starting a personal project using Spring Boot and it is been 3 days facing a severe problem. No matter where I look, even older questions or related issues, I keep facing the same issue.

It is probably going to be a "silly" thing, but I am unable to locate and solve my error. Error is the following one:

> Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/proyecto/springbootapp/config/PersistenceJPAConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.util.NoSuchElementException

I know that my entityManagerFactory is not being generated, but I cannot understand why is it not. I have been following this tutorial in order to archieve this: https://www.baeldung.com/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-and-jpa

Is it that my Hibernate Entities are bad? Perhaps it is due to some pom dependencies? I have tried all I could and yet have no way to detect where exactly my problem is.

Both Code and Database can be found here:

https://github.com/Geothrill/proyecto/tree/master/proyectoiespsur

Full stacktrace goes as follows:

```
<code>
2019-05-23 21:58:33.322  INFO 2368 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.9.Final}
2019-05-23 21:58:33.324  INFO 2368 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000205: Loaded properties from resource hibernate.properties: {spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/proyecto?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC&autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false, spring.datasource.username=root, spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update, spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver, spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1, spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy, spring.datasource.password=root, spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect, hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer=false, spring.datasource.testWhileIdle=true, spring.jpa.show-sql=true}
2019-05-23 21:58:33.455  INFO 2368 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2019-05-23 21:58:34.061  INFO 2368 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2019-05-23 21:58:34.264  WARN 2368 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/proyecto/springbootapp/config/PersistenceJPAConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.util.NoSuchElementException
2019-05-23 21:58:34.268  INFO 2368 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2019-05-23 21:58:34.276  INFO 2368 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-05-23 21:58:34.282 ERROR 2368 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/proyecto/springbootapp/config/PersistenceJPAConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1778) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at com.proyecto.springbootapp.Application.main(Application.java:13) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: null
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:854) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.TableBinder.linkJoinColumnWithValueOverridingNameIfImplicit(TableBinder.java:724) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.PkDrivenByDefaultMapsIdSecondPass.doSecondPass(PkDrivenByDefaultMapsIdSecondPass.java:37) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1696) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1653) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:287) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:904) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:935) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) ~[spring-orm-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) ~[spring-orm-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
</code>
```

Honestly, any help is to be welcomed. I am sorry if I "broke" any rule of posting in this Site, as I admit not having read them.

Comment: The exception stacktrace indicates that Hibernate is unable to build the entity metadata, probably due to an incorrect mapping declaration. First remove all entities from the project, start it to make sure there are no errors, stop, add one entity at a time, start again. When you hit the error again, that will be the problematic entity.

Comment: i tried removing that before for each entity, but once i join the 5 of them, 2 of them are not correctly displayed and dont work. Can this be an issue related to onetomany manytoone annotations?

Comment: Yes, one of those annotations has not been coded correctly. Try enabling one by one to see which one is causing the problem.

Comment: thanks, will do, I will let you know the result once I am able to fix it

Comment: sorry to keep you waiting @manish , you were right, I was able to finally solve the issue by understanding how to create correctly Entities, the rest of the work was a piece of cake. Many thanks